# Creating a moveable and resizeable line in winforms

Tags: c++, winforms, c++-cli

I want to create a program in which the user has an area where he can take lines which I provide him with (for example three lines) and adjust their sizes and locations to create a small diagram.

How can I do that with winforms?

What classes and properties should I use?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You must give some more details. What do you mean by "area", "lines" and "small diagram" ?

Comment: area- box containing all the lines.  lines - small graphical lines, like in paintbrush.  small diagram - all the three lines together.

Comment: So by the [c++-cli] tag, I understand that you want information regarding the "managed" approach of winforms, right?

Comment: I am not sure what is the "managed" approach.  I use winforms, is that a managed approach?

Comment: here "managed winforms" means C++ Windows Forms Application Project. It has /clr option enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand from your question, that you want to give users ability to adjust the size and locations ( similar to anchors in Powerpoint and several other products ) and let him/her draw a figure out of that.

You need to use the graphics functions in that case, though some of your work like resizing might need usage of ovveriding DragDrop method too.

Here is an sample http://www.yevol.com/en/vcsharp/applicationdesign/Lesson14.htm , that might be of help to you.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want a .net solution, have a look at [OpenS-CAD](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/OpenS-CAD.aspx),a sample "2D CAD" project for starting. The thing is, it is written in C#, but it will give you the notion of a CAD program.

You can rewrite it with C++/Cli, and also some parts of it with native C++.